# Порядок установки времени в миллисекундах и временной зоны для Instant

Tags: java, время

Есть класс:

```
public class TimeWrapper {

    private final Instant time;

    private final ZoneId zoneId;

    public TimeWrapper(long millisecondTime, String zone) {
        time = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisecondTime);
        time.atZone(zoneId = ZoneId.of(zone));
    }
    ...
}
```

Том что я с начала устанавливаю время в миллисекундах а потом уже устанавливаю зону делает код не корректным? Ведь миллисекунды считаются с определенного момента и зона должны бать установлена раньше, но это не как не получается потому что надо сначала создать `Instant`.

Или это корректно и будет работать правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Документация к `Instant.ofEpochMilli()`, говорит, что:

> The epoch-seconds are measured from the standard Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z

Это означает, что время устанавливается для "нулевой" временной зоны, так что все ок, не играет роли очередность сначала устанавливаете время, потом временную зону или наоборот. Время которое вы устанавливаете привязано к *zulu/UTC* временной зоне.